# Interpreting notation for binary loss function

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning

I am taking a advanced machine learning class, and in the class notes I noticed a notation that I did not recognize. It is the notation for *binary loss function* (Please note that it is not *binary cross entropy* loss)

In the context of binary classification, the binary loss function is defined as

$$
        (l \circ f)(x_i, y_i) =  \textbf{1}_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]}
$$

Where,
$x_i$ = Feature vector of i-th sample
$y_i$ = True label of i-th sample
$f$ = Function which represents the machine learning model
$l$ = Loss function

Here, $f(x_i) \in \{ 0,1 \}$ and $y_i \in \{ 0,1 \}$, so it is a binary classification problem. Also, in the notes, the following is mentioned,

If $f(x_i) = y_i$ then $ 1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 1$, otherwise, $ 1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 0$

Which, I think can be interpreted as, if the output of the model matches with the true label, the loss is 0 otherwise the loss is 1. However, if this interpretation is true, then shouldn't it be the other way around? i.e. should it be

If $ f(x_i) = y_i, 1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 0$, otherwise, $ 1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 1 $

Because loss should be 0, whenever the model's output matches the true label, otherwise, if it doesn't match, loss should be higher.

I am just trying to match my interpretation with the class notes. If my interpretation is correct, then there seems to be a mistake in the class note. Otherwise, my interpretation might be wrong.

Comment: Yes.  $\mathbf{1}_{[X]}=1$ iff $X$ is "true".

Comment: It seems to want to saying the loss is $1$ when $f(x_i) \neq y_i$ and is $0$  when $f(x_i) = y_i$ but may have confused itself.  Your "should it be" attempt looks correct

Comment: I discussed this with the TA preparing the notes and he confirmed it :). There was a mistake in the notes.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in the notes. It should be,

If $f(x_i) = y_i$ then $1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 0$, otherwise $1_{[f(x_i) \neq y_i]} = 1$

Confirmed by the person who prepared the notes.